# ajax for getting value of jquery price slider on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have implemented a price slider on my website in purpose of making a ajax filter which is well working with the `onclick` function and is able to send values when click on `id slider-range`, but i need to get the value of the amount whenever the amount changes. I have also checked some of the question earlier not working with code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showValues() {
  $("#productContainer").css("opacity",0.5);
  $("#loaderID").css("opacity",1);
  
  //e.css('visibility','visible');
  
    
  var mainarray = new Array();
  var pricearray1 = new Array();  
  $('#amount').each(function(){   
   pricearray1.push($(this).val());
   $('.spanpricecls').css('visibility','visible');  
  });
  if(pricearray1=='') $('.spanpricecls').css('visibility','hidden');
  var price_checklist1 = "&price_range1="+pricearray1;
  
  var main_string = price_checklist1;
  main_string = main_string.substring(1, main_string.length)
  alert(main_string);
        
      $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../../filter_products1.php",
   data: main_string, 
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){
    //alert(html);
    $("#productContainer").html(html);  
    $("#productContainer").css("opacity",1);
    $("#loaderID").css("opacity",0);
    
    
    
   }
   });
  
  
 }
   //calling ajax on selector  
$("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio'], div#slider-range").on( "click", showValues );
  
  $(".spanpricecls").click(function(){
  $('.price_range').removeAttr('checked'); showValues();
  $('.spanpricecls').css('visibility','hidden');
 });
  
 $(".clear_filters").click(function(){
  $('#productCategoryLeftPanel').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
  $('#productCategoryLeftPanel').find('input[type=radio]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
  showValues();
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
  <div id=" productContainer">
vxzcvcxzvvczzzzzzzxc
  
  </div>

 
</body>
</html>
```